# BottomNavigationView no Animation

Tags: java, android, bottomnavigationview

My BottomNavigationView has no animation when changing items. I saw some videos on YouTube, and they have everything the same. And you see the animation well. What do I have to add? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a ViewPager to store your items (fragments). Then for each bottom navigation item, set the viewpager's current item to have the animation effect.

```
mNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        // switch ViewPager items for each bottom navigation item
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_home:
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To turn on animation try to use:

```
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
```

in your BottomNavigationView